# How to build GraphQL Request with Moshi model objects

Tags: java, json, moshi

My current project employs GraphQL.

I wish to investigate Moshi as my Json parser however I am experiencing difficulties in generating my GraphQL response json

This is the Json Request message format I require:

```
{
    "operationName": "androidMyQuery",
    "query": "query androidMyQuery .......",
    "variables": {
            "foo": 400,
            "bar": 200,
            "baz": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

This is what Moshi generates:-

```
{
    "operationName": "androidMyQuery",
    "query": "query androidMyQuery .......",
    "variables": {
        "variables": {
            "foo": 400,
            "bar": 200,
            "baz": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }
}
```

My Java model classes resemble this:-

```
public class GraphqlRequest {

    @Json(name = "operationName")
    private String operationName;

    @Json(name = "variables")
    private Variables variables;

    @Json(name = "query")
    private String query;

}
```

And

```
public class Variables {

    private Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Object> getVariables() {
        return this.variables;
    }

    public void setVariable(final String name, final Object value) {
        this.variables.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

How do I achieve my desired result and keep the model classes above?

Comment: The problem is your `Variables` class, with its nested `getVariables` getter. Why make an extra wrapper there, why not directly store that `Map<String, Object>` on the `GraphqlRequest`?

Comment: Either write a [custom type adapter](https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-type-adapters) for your `Variables` class that returns the `Map`, or create a `getVariables` method on `GraphqlRequest` that returns the `variables.getVariables()`.

Comment: I employ jsonschema2pojo to generate all my model classes and I believe the "extra" Variables class is technically correct in representing this Json structure as Variables is an Object in the Json. By the way JACKSON handles this "extra" Wrapper class with no issues.